# Order of FindObjectsOfType method in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the Method FindObjectsOfType inside Unity and I want to know what the order Unity find objects?
I tried to change the order of my game objects inside the hierarchy and even change the name of my game objects to 1_name, 2_otherName and still the list seems random.

Do it really random or there is an order for the search? There is no documentation about the order in the Unity website.

If someone really want, this is my relevent script:

```
[SerializeField] List<AreaMeshHandler> areaMeshHandlers;

void Awake()
{
     areaMeshHandlers = FindObjectsOfType<AreaMeshHandler>(true).ToList();
}
```

Comment: In case you have not heard that in other places: Try to avoid FindObjectsOfType. This is a full on search operation and becomes slower the more objects there are in the whole scene. What you can do instead, let your AreaMeshHandler add their references to a list in a manger object in their Start() method.

Comment: I know but sometime it's a best idea to use it, at this time it was best for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, by InstanceID. can be seen on each GameObject in debug mode.

Tested by running this code in a scene with multiple GameObjects (some in hierarchy)

```
        foreach (Target t in FindObjectsOfType<Target>())
            Debug.Log($"{t.name}: {t.GetInstanceID()}");
```